# Is there any way to access WordPress files except theme editor, ftp and file manager(cPanel)?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

While editing theme's functions.php file an error occurred and I've lost the access to theme editor, cause the site was down.

I don't have logins for FTP or cPanel.
Is there anyway to recover the site only with WordPress logins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have FTP or cPanel then I guess you don't have ssh access too. If your hosting service provider offers ssh access then you can try that. Otherwise, I'm afraid there's no way!